# Matplotlib needs careful timing? (Or is there a flag to show plotting is done?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code does not work as expected:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(100000), '.')
plt.draw()

ax = plt.gca()
lblx = ax.get_xticklabels()
lblx[1]._text = 'hello!'
ax.set_xticklabels(lblx)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following figure:
[image]

I imagine that the reason is that the automatic xticklabels did not have time to be fully created when `get_xticklabels()` was called. And indeed, by adding `plt.pause(1)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(100000), '.')
plt.draw()
plt.pause(1)

ax = plt.gca()
lblx = ax.get_xticklabels()
lblx[1]._text = 'hello!'
ax.set_xticklabels(lblx)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

would give the expected

[image]

I'm not very happy with this state (having to manually insert delays). And my main concern is: How can I know how much time I need to wait? Surely it depends on number of figure elements, machine strength, etc..

So my question is: Is there some flag to know that matplotlib has finished drawing all the elements? Or is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Works as expected on my machine with matplotlib 2.1.2.

Comment: @MaxPowers, I'm also on 2.1.2. Maybe your machine is stronger? Would it matter if you increase the number of points to be plotted?

Comment: Or plot something with more xticks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it should be noted that you may make an arbitrarily short pause

```
plt.pause(1e-18)
```

The issue here is that `plt.draw()` calls `plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()`. This means that the figure is drawn at some arbitrary point when there is time to do it - hence the `_idle`.

Instead you would probably want to draw the figure at the specific point in the code you need.

```
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(100000), '.')
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()

ax = plt.gca()
lblx = ax.get_xticklabels()
lblx[1]._text = 'hello!'
ax.set_xticklabels(lblx)

plt.show()
```